# I cannot access injected services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is an angulars app. I have a service declared this way:

```
define([], function() {
    function myService(anotherService, alerts) {
        //doing stuff here
        this.callMe = function(msg){
            myfunc(msg)
        }
    }

    function myfunc(msg) {
        alerts.Success(msg);
    }

    myService.$inject = ['anotherService', 'alerts'];
    return myService;
});
```

I initiate the service and at some point I call a function in it:

```
myService.callMe("hello");
```

The injected services (in this case the one named "alerts") are undefined.
If I call them from inside the function "callMe" then it works.
This service has been for some reason build in that way, where the function "myfunc" has been declared outside "myService".
Im not sure what it has been done this way.
If I move it inside the service then Iget some error with the "require"-module.
What would you suggest? Is there a way for the function outside the declaration of the service to access injected services?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to add the injected service as a parameter:

```
define([], function() {
    function myService(anotherService, alerts) {
        //doing stuff here
        this.callMe = function(msg){
            ̶m̶y̶f̶u̶n̶c̶(̶m̶s̶g̶)̶
            myfunc(alerts, msg)
        }
    }

    ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶m̶y̶f̶u̶n̶c̶(̶m̶s̶g̶)
    function myfunc(alerts, msg) {
        alerts.Success(msg);
    }

    myService.$inject = ['anotherService', 'alerts'];
    return myService;
});
```

Comment: Now I don't get the "undefined"-error. But nothing happens. No alert (its not the common alert, but something more fancy imported by that library) shows up.